# Error in mySparkDF.show() : could not find function "mySparkDF.show"

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'm want to start working with sparkR followed tutorials but I get the below error:

```
library(SparkR)
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/Users/myuserhone/dev/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
  .libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"R","lib"), .libPaths()))

spark <- sparkR.session(appName = "mysparkr", Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), master = "local[*]")

csvPath <- "file:///Users/myuserhome/dev/spark-data/donation"
mySparkDF <- read.df(csvPath, "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "?")
mySparkDF.show()
```

But I get:

```
Error in mySparkDF.show() : could not find function "mySparkDF.show"
```

Not sure what I do wrong, in addition, I don't have code completion for the spark functions like `read.df(...)`

In addition if I try

```
show(describe(mySparkDF))
```

or

```
show(summary(mySparkDF))
```

I get in results the metadata and not the "describe" expected result

```
SparkDataFrame[summary:string, id_1:string, id_2:string, cmp_fname_c1:string, cmp_fname_c2:string, cmp_lname_c1:string, cmp_lname_c2:string, cmp_sex:string, cmp_bd:string, cmp_bm:string, cmp_by:string, cmp_plz:string]
```

Anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` is not used in such a way in SparkR, neither it serves the same purpose with the same-name command in PySpark; you should use either [`head`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/head.html) or [`showDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/showDF.html):

```
df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)

show(df)
# result:
SparkDataFrame[eruptions:double, waiting:double]

head(df)
# result:
   eruptions waiting
 1     3.600      79
 2     1.800      54
 3     3.333      74
 4     2.283      62
 5     4.533      85
 6     2.883      55

showDF(df)
# result:
+---------+-------+
|eruptions|waiting|
+---------+-------+
|      3.6|   79.0|
|      1.8|   54.0|
|    3.333|   74.0|
|    2.283|   62.0|
|    4.533|   85.0|
|    2.883|   55.0|
|      4.7|   88.0|
|      3.6|   85.0|
|     1.95|   51.0|
|     4.35|   85.0|
|    1.833|   54.0|
|    3.917|   84.0|
|      4.2|   78.0|
|     1.75|   47.0|
|      4.7|   83.0|
|    2.167|   52.0|
|     1.75|   62.0|
|      4.8|   84.0|
|      1.6|   52.0|
|     4.25|   79.0|
+---------+-------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: thanks, i was sure I could have the same api as i have with scala spark on sparkR .. so I understand if i want to use scala-spark and sparkR I need to learn two things :/ thanks!

Comment: thanks, also it's frustrating i don't get code completion in `rstudio` for example for `read.df(csvPath, "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "?")` for the parameters, do you have code completion for it?

Comment: @Jas I don't, but I am not actually using it either